# Can I set multiple physics?

Tags: vis.js, vis.js-network

Is there a way to define different physics for different sets of edges?

What I want to achieve, is to pull nodes together, who are in the same cluster, and to push those nodes away, who have a different cluster.

At the moment I define the physics in options:

```
const options = {
  physics: {
    enabled: true,
    barnesHut: {
      gravitationalConstant: -80000, 
      springConstant: 0.001, 
      springLength: 200,
      centralGravity: 0,
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While reading the documentation, I figured out that there is no way to set different physics.

But there is a way to **deactivate** the physics for specific nodes or edges.

Therefore you have to override the global options for the nodes/ edges.
This can be achieved by defining the options in the node/edge itself.

```
 var nodes = new vis.DataSet([
    { id: 1, label: "Node 1" },
    { id: 2, label: "Node 2" },
    { id: 3, label: "Node 3" },
    { id: 4, label: "Node 4" },
    { id: 5, label: "Node 5" }
  ]);

  // create an array with edges
  var edges = new vis.DataSet([
    { from: 1, to: 3, physics: false },
    { from: 1, to: 2, physics: false },
    { from: 2, to: 4 },
    { from: 2, to: 5 },
    { from: 3, to: 3 }
  ]);

  // create a network
  var container = document.getElementById("mynetwork");
  var data = {
    nodes: nodes,
    edges: edges
  };
  var options = {
    physics: {
      enabled: true,
    }
  };

  var network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);
```

In this example, the edges [from 1 to 3] and [from 1 to 2] are overriding the global physics options and therefore they don't act as springs.